# Xcodeで実機テストができなくなりました。"Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"というエラー

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, macos, swift5

昨日突然Xocdeで実機テストができなくなりました。

エラー文は以下のとおりです。

```swift
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

エラー文付近には以下のような記述がありました。

```swift
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Intermediates.noindex/demo2.build/Debug-iphoneos/demo2.build/Script-024CAB14D5D4ECD45067AA1C.sh (in target 'demo2' from project 'demo2')
    cd /Users/◯◯◯/Documents/GitHub/demoapp
    /bin/sh -c /Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Intermediates.noindex/demo2.build/Debug-iphoneos/demo2.build/Script-024CAB14D5D4ECD45067AA1C.sh

mkdir -p /Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/demo2.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppAuth/AppAuth.framework" "/Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/demo2.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
deleting AppAuth.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
deleting AppAuth.framework/_CodeSignature/
AppAuth.framework/

sent 146 bytes  received 26 bytes  344.00 bytes/sec
total size is 441267  speedup is 2565.51
Code Signing /Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/demo2.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework with Identity Apple Development: ◯◯◯ (XDS7AXXXBG)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign F6B2CB887D02116C81F80A6FD8D4F3C7E29CC2BF  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/demo2.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework'
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: ◯◯◯ (XDS7AXXXBG)"
/Users/◯◯◯/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo2-cuxtcawdfrqcqafwplsfrvhdggep/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/demo2.app/Frameworks/AppAuth.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

ネットで調べて出てきた内容↓

・すべてのキーチェーンをロックしてから実機テスト
・Macの再起動
・Xcodeの再起動
・iPhoneの再起動
・Apple Developerで証明書の作り直し
・XcodeからApple IDをログアウト

といったことは試しましたが特に変化はありませんでした。

Xcode→Preference→Account→Manage Certificatesは以下のような画面となっております。

[image: 名前は隠しております]

シミュレーターでは起動ができるので証明書、キーチェーン関連が原因だと思われるのですが何が原因なのでしょうか？

原因や解決方法をどなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: エラーログ中に「AppAuth.framework」というものが現れていますが、それはご自身で作成されたフレームワークでしょうか? [Appleのdev forumsにも同エラーが出たという報告](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/675880)がありますが、まだ解決に至るような回答はついていないようです。(使用しているのは別のフレームワーク。)「最新のフレームワークが最新のXcodeまたはApple側サーバの動作に対応していない」「Apple側の(署名関連の処理を行う)サーバに(一時的?)不調が発生している」等と言ったことが考えられます。自作ではないフレームワーク等を使用されている場合、開発元のサポートサイト・情報交換サイトなどにいけば、何か手がかりがあるかもしれません。

Comment: forumsの紹介までありがとうございます。AppAuthというファイルは自作でもなくライブラリでもなく、実機で立ち上げる時に自動で生成されているようです。一度削除してみたのですがビルドする際にファイルが追加されていたので。引き続き調べてみることにします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。AppAuthなんてどこにもでありそうな名前なんでAppleがビルドに埋め込んでいる可能性がないとも言い切れないんですが、podなどのパッケージマネージャーを使っているなら、依存フレームワークに指定されていると「一度削除してみたのですがビルドする際にファイルが追加されていた」というのは普通に起こるので、もし何らかのライブラリを使っているなら、そのどれかを疑ってみるといいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

Certificatesやprofile関連のファイルをすべて０からやり直して

Apple DeveloperのCertificatesから

Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority (Expiring 02/07/2023)

を追加したところ直りました。

ご協力いただいた方ありがとうございました。